# Can't set up Kohana using two instances without crashing the whole system

Tags: php, kohana-3

My Kohana enviroment is setup already on my webroot path, and I need to move it inside my application. It is currently three (3) levels deep. When I access my Kohana site it says it does not exists anymore. It returns "Object not found".

Is it possible to rename Kohana `base_url` to something else, without crashing the whole system? If yes, which files do I need to modify?

I have two installations of Kohana in my web server:

- First installation path - `http://localhost/kohana/`
- Second installation path - `http://localhost/haz/system/framework/`

Where **framework** is my Kohana, the first installation works perfectly.

The second one I did the modifications in the `bootstrap (base_url)` and added the full URL: **http://localhost/haz/system/framework/** to access it.

When I try to access via the browser I can only access the welcome page but the rest comes from the first installation.

For example, I have a (controller/model/view) called **Customers**. When I try to access the **customers**, it shows up the **customers** of the **first installation** and not the second as expected.

I think there are some other files that I do need to modify along with the **path** in bootstrap, because the `base_url` with the full URL did not fix the problem.

Either that or Kohana doesn't accept two installations in the same web server.

Raw PHP is much easier and faster for me, but repetition is giving a lot of headache, so I'm trying to use the Kohana framework. If it gives me more headaches I think I'll stick to raw PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your bootstrap file in `application/bootstrap.php` then search for the line `Kohana::init`. One of the parameters of this function, should be the base URL, so you can change it here to whatever you want. If it's not already set (unlikely), you can add it manually:

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => "http://thebase.com/url", /* No trailing slash */
));
```

**Edit:**

Without looking into the details, is there any reason why you have the framework's file in a different location? In general, Kohana is lightweight enough so that you can put the whole framework with each application.

Also, when you talk about a Kohana's installation, do you mean the `system` and `modules` folders or all of the Kohana files (including `application`). If it's the latter, there is something wrong with your configuration because the `application` folder obviously cannot be shared by different applications.

If you can, try to move the whole Kohana framework next to your application folder, with the normal application/modules/system folder structure, then tweak the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had edited my question, I did as you mentioned to me, but without success. I still thinking it is a problem in the path somewhere else.. since I do not have yet the insight of the whole thing as it works..  thanks anyway, still trying to discovery the problem.

Comment: @FernandoCosta, I've edited my answer with some more information. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: I have two different installation (including application folder each one) of kohana in my web-server because it is a development environment. For now I have renamed the root installation to something else, and when I access my second installation It still trying to access the first one. It is weird! For sure is configuration, but where? :(

Comment: @FernandoCosta, it's quite difficult to know what's happening because it could also be some issue with your hosts file, Apache, etc. Just in case, make sure that your .htaccess  file is correct. In particular, the `RewriteBase` line should be changed to `RewriteBase /your/path/`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no ideas around what hell is going on. Then I will give up and back to RAW php, as I said I do not have to much time to waste understanding how stuffs works, I just need stuffs working like RAW php do. @Laurent Thank You very much for your time.

Comment: No problem, good luck with that. In your next project, definitely give another try to Kohana. After having tried many frameworks, it's the one that made me switch to pure PHP to "framework PHP".

Comment: Perheps if you know some tutorial step by step how to setup kohana framework properly in very different ways, I will be very greatful. And sure I'm looking for a framework, I really need it, but at the moment no time. Anyway thanks for your time.

Comment: I will accept your answer and plus one 'cause the stimulus you gave me to not gave up with kohana.